# Calling camera does not return to the caller's onActivityResult

Tags: android

I have an ActivityA that calls an ActivityB using startActivityForResult. So far, when buttons OK/Cancel are clicked in ActivityB, it returns to ActivityA, as expected. Now, I'm trying to take pictures from ActivityB, so I call startActivityForResult for an Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) object. When my take photo button is clicked, the camera displays correctly.

However, when I click OK or Cancel buttons in the camera, ActivityB.onActivityResult is not called. Instead, ActivityA.onActivityResult gets called.

I have a similar code elsewhere, in which an activity calls the camera, and OK/Cancel returns to the caller's onActivityResult, as expected. The only difference I notice is that the caller's activity was originally created with startActivity, whereas this one was created with startActivityForResult.

Why this functions this way? How can I achieve my goal, or what am I missing? My target is Android 7, min support is Android 4.4.

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` is not really designed for this sort of chaining. I recommend taking some other approach.

Comment: @CommonsWare what was designed for, then? What would be the correct approach?

Comment: "what was designed for, then?" -- it was designed for a single hop (`startActivityForResult()` reaching a dialog-style activity that does its work and returns the result). "What would be the correct approach?" -- I do not know much about your app and so I cannot provide much concrete advice. Off the cuff, perhaps these should not be separate activities, but instead be a single activity with a changing UI (e.g., via fragments).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your input. The scenario is as follows. It's a master/detail, where users capture head data in ActivityA, and can input many child data, which is captured in ActivityB. But the child data must support having an image, hence the need to call the camera capture. Surely it's a fairly common scenario. 

I'll take a look into the fragments you mention, see if I can make it work that way. Thanks again!

Comment: "Surely it's a fairly common scenario" -- yes, but master/detail is usually implemented via fragments. Moreover, even if you were to use activities, you do not need to use `startActivityForResult()`. Have ActivityB update some shared data model, which ActivityA examines when it returns to the foreground.